# Laravel: Joining tables in Laravel and loop on the other tables

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I am joining 3 tables, property, facilities, and images.
A property has many facilities and has many images.

On my query its looping the same property how many times it has facilities and images and each loop is getting 1 facility and 1 image.
What I need to accomplish is it will loop per property and will get all facilities and images a property has.

```
        $properties = DB::table('properties')
        ->join('facilities', 'properties.id', '=', 'facilities.property_id')
        ->join('images', 'properties.id', '=', 'images.property_id')
        ->select('properties.*', 'facilities.feature_name', 'images.img_url')
        ->paginate(10);
```

Property Model

```
public function facilities() {
    return $this->hasMany(Facility::class);
}

public function images() {
    return $this->hasMany(Image::class);
}
```

Facility Model

```
public function property() {
    return $this->belongsTo(Property::class);
}
```

Image Model

```
public function property() {
    return $this->belongsTo(Property::class);
}
```

Blade

```
    @foreach ($properties as $property)
        {{ $property->title }}, 
    @endforeach
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can [eager load](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#nested-eager-loading) your relation:

```
    $properties=\App\Models\Property::with(['facilities:property_id,feature_name','images:property_id,img_url'])->paginate(10);
```

in blade you may do something like:

```
@foreach ($properties as $property)
        {{ $property->title }}
          @foreach ($property->facilities as $facility)
               {{ $facility->feature_name}}
          @endforeach
        // for the images you can do the same 
          
    @endforeach
```